# Symfony3: Correspondence of key value reversal in Choice Type

Tags: php, symfony

I'm updating Symfony.
When I upgraded to Symfony3, all the "State." Names displayed on the form changed to numbers.
All state values are set in services.yml. By reversing the yml value, the display in the browser was restored, but when I tried to save the value selected in the pull-down in the form, the system works to save the number instead of "State.".
Is there any good solution?
Also, I don't want to use `` `choices_as_value``` because it will not be usable in the future.

**Code**
Type

```php
        $builder->add("prefId", ChoiceType::class, array(
            "required" => true,
            "choices" => Parameters::getParameter("state"),
        ));
```

services.yml

```yaml
    state:
      //Symfoyn 2
        1: "Alabama"
      //Symfony 3
        "Alabama": 1
```

**Version**
Symfony3.0.9
PHP 5.6

Comment: One of the more amusing Symfony Form BC breaks was the decision to reverse the key/value order for choice arrays.  It's always been a bit of a mystery as to why.  There is an option you can use to change it back though I forget what it is.  You probably just need to adjust Parameters::getParameter to reverse the order or possible use array_flip as a work around.

Comment: If you have not already then you might want to get familiar with what Symfony calls the [Living on the Edge](https://symfony.com/blog/category/living-on-the-edge/3.0-2.8) blog.  Most changes and enhancements are usually described somewhere in this blog.  It can sometimes be a bit challenging to find a specific article but it can be worthwhile just to sort of browse through the titles.  Not to be overly discouraging but if you plan to bring this app up to current standards then you have a long ways to go.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for your comment. Thanks to your tips I was able to solve the problem. Also, thank you for telling me a useful url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing `array_keys` in Parameter.php to `array_reverse`. Thanks to Cerad.

```php
    //Parameter.php
   /**
     * 
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public static function getState()
    {
        return self::$container->getParameter("state");
    }

    /**
     * 
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public static function getStateKeys()
    {
        //return array_keys(self::getState());
        return array_reverse(self::getState());
    }
```